# how to change file directory path become reading file path

Tags: python, directory

I would like to read the current directory and make it become reading directory later

```
master1.filename = filedialog.askdirectory() # return current directory
```

and my problem will be the "/" , when the return result is using "/" and i need  "\" in reading, and how should I make it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `os.path.normpath(path)` or other helpful methods in os.path module.

Comment: code not working~

Comment: Best to show your full code.

Comment: you code is correct, is working and thanks